# Scheme Ill informed syntax

Tags: scheme

I am getting this error:

> ;Ill-formed syntax: (define (mycount (lambda (n lst) (cond ((null?
> lst) 0) ((= (car lst) n) (+ 1 (mycount n (cdr lst)))) (else (mycount n
> (cdr lst)))))))

this is my code

```
  (lambda (n lst)
    (cond
      ((null? lst) 0)
      ((= (car lst) n) (+ 1 (mycount n (cdr lst))))
      (else (mycount n (cdr lst)))))))

(define (tagmatch
  (lambda (n lst)
    (cond
      ((null? lst) '())
      ((=(car lst)n) (cons 1(tagmatch n(cdr lst))))
      (else (cons 0 (tagmatch n(cdr lst)))))))
```

Answer (score 0):

You haven't posted the complete definition for `mycount`, but the parentheses are misplaced (and miscounted) in the definition for `tagmatch`, and this suggests that the parentheses are also incorrectly placed in `mycount`.

When a `define` form is used to bind an object to a variable, no parentheses are needed around the variable. Parentheses are only needed when using the `defun`-style syntactic sugar to define a procedure.

```
(define mycount
  (lambda (n lst)
    (cond ((null? lst) 0)
          ((= (car lst) n)
           (+ 1 (mycount n (cdr lst))))
          (else
           (mycount n (cdr lst))))))

(define tagmatch
  (lambda (n lst)
    (cond ((null? lst) '())
          ((= (car lst) n)
           (cons 1 (tagmatch n (cdr lst))))
          (else
           (cons 0 (tagmatch n(cdr lst)))))))
```

Here `define` binds the anonymous procedures described in the `lambda` expressions to `mycount` and `tagmatch`, respectively. Scheme has syntactic sugar for defining a procedure without an explicit `lambda` expression; in that case parentheses are needed to group the name of the procedure with its arguments:

```
(define (mycount n lst)
  (cond ((null? lst) 0)
        ((= (car lst) n)
         (+ 1 (mycount n (cdr lst))))
        (else
         (mycount n (cdr lst)))))
```